# Airflow - Script executes during initialization

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have a Airflow script that is expected to insert data from table_2 to table_1. As part of the initialization process of airflow I see the insert function keeps running in the background even though I have not triggered it or scheduled. I am wondering what is wrong in the script that makes it trigger automatically. What do I need to modify in the below script to ensure it does not execute the command as part of the initialization process.

```
## Library Imports
import psycopg2
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators import BashOperator
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import io


# Following are defaults which can be overridden later on
default_args = {
'owner': 'admin',
'depends_on_past': False,
'start_date': datetime(2018, 5, 25),
'email': ['admin@mail.com'],
'email_on_failure': True,
'email_on_retry': True,
'retries': 1,
'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1),
}

dag = DAG('sample', default_args=default_args)


#######################

def db_login():
    global db_con
try:
    db_con = psycopg2.connect(" dbname = 'db' user = 'user' password = 'pass' host = 'hostname' port = '5439' sslmode = 'require' ")
except:
    print("I am unable to connect to the database.")
print('Connection Task Complete: Connected to DB')
return(db_con)


#######################

def insert_data():
    cur = db_con.cursor()
    cur.execute("""insert into table_1 select id,name,status from table_2 limit 2 ;""")
    db_con.commit()
    print('ETL Task Complete: Inserting data into table_1')


db_login()
insert_data()
db_con.close()

##########################################


t1 = BashOperator(
task_id='db_con',
python_callable=db_login(),
bash_command='python3 ~/airflow/dags/sample.py',
email_on_failure=True,
email=['admin@mail.com'],
dag=dag)

t2 = BashOperator(
task_id='insert',
python_callable=insert_data(),
bash_command='python3 ~/airflow/dags/sample.py',
email_on_failure=True,
email=['admin@mail.com'],
dag=dag)


t1.set_downstream(t2)
```

Could anyone assist on this. Thanks.

**Updated Code:**

```
## Third party Library Imports

import psycopg2
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import io



default_args = {
'owner': 'admin',
#'depends_on_past': False,
'start_date': datetime(2018, 5, 25),
 'email': ['admin@mail.com'],
 'email_on_failure': True,
 'email_on_retry': True,
 'retries': 1,
 'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1), }

dag = DAG('sample', default_args=default_args, catchup=False, schedule_interval="@once")


def db_login():
    global db_con
    try:
        db_con = psycopg2.connect(
        " dbname = 'db' user = 'user' password = 'password' host = 'host' port = '5439' sslmode = 'require' ")
    except:
        print("I am unable to connect to the database.")
    print('Connection success')
    return (db_con)

def insert_data():
    cur = db_con.cursor()
    cur.execute("""insert into table_1 select id,name,status from table_2 limit 2;""")
    db_con.commit()
    print('ETL Task Complete: Inserting data into table_1')

def load_etl():
    db_login()
    insert_data()
    dwh_connection.close()

#Function to execute the query
load_etl()

t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='db_connection',
    python_callable=load_etl(),
    bash_command='python3 ~/airflow/dags/sample.py',
    email_on_failure=True,
    email=['admin@mail.com'],
    dag=dag)

#t2 = BashOperator(
#task_id='ops_load_del',
#python_callable=insert_data(),
#bash_command='python3 ~/airflow/dags/sample.py',
#email_on_failure=True,
#email=['admin@mail.com'],
#dag=dag)

t1
#t1.set_downstream(t2)
```

Comment: @tobi6, apologies for the confusion. I have edited the code. Could you please have a look. Thanks..

Comment: I hope you looking at the Updated code section above. Also the formatting for the Python section is correct as I am able to get the expected output for that part when I run it at my end. The problem I am having is since the function I have is expected to insert rows into a table, when I start Airflow (using "airflow initdb"), the query starts executing on its own even though I have not triggered or scheduled it to run. Figuring how I could ensure this doesn't run in the background without the user triggering.. Hope this helps. Tnx..

Comment: @tobi6, sorry about that but could you please have one last look. Believe I did not do the spacing correctly all this while. Tnx..

Comment: @tobi6, thanks for your input. I wasn't aware we should be using PythonOperator in case if we calling functions. I have modified that along with the function name. However I still see the inserting happening automatically during initialization. :(

Comment: @tobi6, Yes i have removed the function. Currently the insert is not happening during initialization. Once the job is triggered, the task_id is labelled under "No Status". Dont see any errors. 

One other change that I did was changed the import for the below library

#from airflow.operators import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

Comment: Please [edit] your question and do not put code in comments. Also, I don't understand the problem now. You might want to open a new question.

Comment: Thanks, I shall start a new thread for this. Appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at your DAG from a Python-esque point of view, the indentation is provoking a few thoughts.

First, try executing the DAG just with `python name-of-dag.py`. Yes, do not use the `airflow` command. This is also being done by some parts of Airflow to check what to do.

Now, if some code is being executed, this might be connected to the intendation.

**Analysis of function**

The indentation here seems broken:

def db_login():
    global db_con
try:
    db_con = psycopg2.connect(" dbname = 'db' user = 'user' password = 'pass' host = 'hostname' port = '5439' sslmode = 'require' ")
except:
    print("I am unable to connect to the database.")
print('Connection Task Complete: Connected to DB')
return(db_con)

It should be:

```
def db_login():
    global db_con
    try:
        db_con = psycopg2.connect(" dbname = 'db' user = 'user' password = 'pass' host = 'hostname' port = '5439' sslmode = 'require' ")
    except:
        print("I am unable to connect to the database.")
    print('Connection Task Complete: Connected to DB')
    return(db_con)
```

Otherwise the code to the very left will always be executed.

Also: **global** variables will not neccesariliy be available within other methods in Airflow! To share connections, use e.g. Airflows `XCOM`: https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#xcoms

**Function calls directly within the DAG**

Also, for some reason unbeknownst to me, you want to execute some functions *completely outside of the control of Airflow* but on every execution.

```
db_login() 
insert_data()
db_con.close()
```

This code will be executed *every time the DAG is called* (which can be a lot) and might be completely different to your wanted schedule.

If you want this code to be there for testing purposes you might want to put it in a main call:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    db_login() 
    insert_data()
    db_con.close()
```

Even if you do - the close operation is only available in this workflow but not in the DAG. There is not task to close the connection.

Since you are using `PythonOperator` it might also be wise to build a small def to do this and only have one task which calls this def:

```
def load_etl():
    db_login() 
    insert_data()
    db_con.close()
```

**TL/DR:**
Eliminate all indentation errors so that if you call the file purely with Python, no code is executed.

**EDIT**

This also means that no function calls are outside of a task or def. This line

```
#Function to execute the query
load_etl()
```

will be executed since it is no part of a task or a def. It has to be removed. Then it should work, since the function call is part of a task.

Since this function is a Python function, you should use a `PythonOperator` and its parameter `python_callable=load_etl` (note: no brackets at the end of the line)

Comment: thanks for your feedback. Believe the alignment for the Python script got misplaced when I entered the values in here. I am able to execute the Python portion of the script and it works just fine as expected. However, could you please help me how to have the functions completely outside of the control of Airflow but on every execution. Thanks..

Comment: yes I did. Have pasted the updated code in the original message. Still have the same problem wherein the script starts running by default when initializing airflow.

Comment: @darkhorse If this answer has helped you, consider marking it as accepted so others can see.